# How to make .NET control work with Autoit as it can work only with STANDARD controls

Tags: .net, automation, autoit

I have the following code

```
 #Include <GuiComboBox.au3>
 #Include <GuiComboBoxEX.au3>
 #include <GUIListBox.au3>
 #include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
;~#AutoIt3Wrapper_Res_requestedExecutionLevel=requireAdministrator 
global $hcombo = "[NAME:ctlMsgQueueCombo]"
global $hcomboclass = "[CLASS:WindowsForms10.COMBOBOX.app.0.2bf8098_r15_ad12]"
global $title = "Test Form"
global $index = 0
WinActivate ($title)
;Start test executable
Run("Z:\test\Info.Test\bin\Debug\Info.Test.exe")
sleep(6000)
controlFocus("", "", "[NAME:ctlSelector]")
controlsend("", "", "[NAME:ctlSelector]", 'QWER67')
sleep(1000)
local $shcombo = ControlGetHandle($title, "", $hcombo)
local $sText = 'TYY Processor (QWERYY980) - Q00S00'
_GUICtrlComboBox_SelectString($shcombo, $sText)
```

As this code is selecting the item from the dropdown but actually not setting the object ref. How can I do it with autoit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AutoIt can work with .NET controls just fine. .NET created controls fall under the category standard controls. Controls such as those made by Java or WPF do not. Being COM accessible has nothing to do with it.

That said, it looks like there are probably some errors in your AutoIt code. I can't say exactly where because I don't understand what "but actually not setting the object ref" means.

Some pointers, use the $title where possible instead of empty string:

```
controlFocus($title, "", "[NAME:ctlSelector]")
controlsend($title, "", "[NAME:ctlSelector]", 'QWER67')
```

_GUICtrlComboBox_SelectString can work with partial strings. So instead of:

```
local $shcombo = ControlGetHandle($title, "", $hcombo)
local $sText = 'TYY Processor (QWERYY980) - Q00S00'
_GUICtrlComboBox_SelectString($shcombo, $sText)
```

Do:

```
local $shcombo = ControlGetHandle($title, "", $hcombo)
local $sText = 'TYY Processor'
_GUICtrlComboBox_SelectString($shcombo, $sText)
```

And see if it works. Please post back with some more information on exactly what is failing. Use proper debug procedures, for example: Always check errors in your code. Don't assume $shcombo is valid etc.

Comment: yes you were right, I was sending a text to a control which is a combo box.

Answer (score 0):

By "standard" controls I'm guessing you mean COM-accessible ones?

If so, then you probably need to make your .NET controls/components usable by the COM interface. Here's a [short explanation](http://generally.wordpress.com/2006/07/28/exposing-your-net-assembly-through-com/), and a [more detailed one](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/visual-studio/build-and-deploy-a-.net-com-assembly/).

Comment: Can you please elaborate, As I am a tester and I have a windows form application to test. In the above e.g Run("Z:\test\Info.Test\bin\Debug\Info.Test.exe") is the path of application under test. And My test scripts are independent of this application. All I am doing is to call this app and then using its GUI test the application by interacting with its control by their Ids. Please tell whose .net control/components I make usable by COM interface. Confused. Please guide